# error in installing knn plugin for elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, macos, elasticsearch

I am trying to install the KNN plugin to get the following code working:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
es = Elasticsearch('http://127.0.0.1:9200',verify_certs=False)
settings={
    "settings":{
     "index": {
      "knn": "true",
      "knn.space_type": "cosinesimil"
    }   
    },
    "mappings":{
        "dynamic": "true",
        "_source":{
            "enabled":"true"
        },
    "properties":{
        "vector": {
            "type": "knn_vector",
            "dimension": "768"
        }
    }
    }
}

es.indices.create(index = 'document_embeddings', ignore=[400,404], body = settings)
```

but am getting the following error:

```
{'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception',
    'reason': 'unknown setting [index.knn] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings'}],
  'type': 'illegal_argument_exception',
  'reason': 'unknown setting [index.knn] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings',
  'suppressed': [{'type': 'illegal_argument_exception',
    'reason': 'unknown setting [index.knn.space_type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings'}]},
 'status': 400}
```

I think the cause is that the KNN plugin is not installed, so I am installing it in the following way where thee zip file is downloaded from [here](https://github.com/alexklibisz/elastiknn/releases/tag/8.6.1.0-MAIN1517-SNAPSHOT).

```
-> Installing file://elastiknn-8.6.1.0.zip
-> Downloading file://elastiknn-8.6.1.0.zip
-> Failed installing file://elastiknn-8.6.1.0.zip
-> Rolling back file://elastiknn-8.6.1.0.zip
-> Rolled back file://elastiknn-8.6.1.0.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: elastiknn-8.6.1.0.zip
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:560)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:1045)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:1010)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1102)
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1088)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:318)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:424)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.cli.InstallPluginAction.downloadZip(InstallPluginAction.java:465)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.cli.InstallPluginAction.download(InstallPluginAction.java:329)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.cli.InstallPluginAction.execute(InstallPluginAction.java:247)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.cli.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
```

The command that I am running to install the plugin is:

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file://elastiknn-8.6.1.0.zip
```

The version of my elasticsearch i.e. **8.6.1** seems perfectly compatible with that of elastiknn. Can anyone please tell me how can I get a working setup of KNN with elasticsearch in my mac? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use type dense vector. Read this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html#exact-knn).